# Spark Shell Read Local Parquet File

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Is it possible to read parquet files from local file system at Spark Shell?

I'm having the problem that it wants to read it from hdfs.

```
sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString=true")
df = sqlContext.parquetFile('/Users/file.parquet')
```

Also tried: `'file:///Users/file.parquet'`

Error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/Users/file.parquet
>   ```

Comment: It is possible, as long as input file is accessible on all workers nodes.

Comment: @zero323 I'd guess he's running spark in local mode.

Comment: Yea, I'm running shell locally.

Answer (score 1):

Everything worked magically when I moved to Spark 1.5 instead of 1.3.